# R ylab line modified with italic

Tags: r, axis-labels

I have trouble making my plots looking similar because my labels (both xlab and ylab) move if I use italic. Consider the following short example:

```
plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab="p-value")
plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab=expression(italic(p)~"-value"))
```

The problem is that "p-value" is slightly nearest from the axis than "*p*-value". I believe it's because the *p* tail defines the writing line which is considered different without italic. How can I fix that easily?

I frequently use both strings and expressions for my plots and that would be complicated to use mtext (with the line argument) to manage each label for each plot.

Comment: Always use `expression`?  `plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab=expression("p-value"))` plots the `ylab` in the same location as `plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab=expression(italic(p)~"-value"))`.

Comment: @Djork that solution would work only if all expressions contain a letter with a tail (p or q). However, consider the difference between `plot(1:10,ylab=expression(italic(p)~"-value"))` and `plot(1:10,ylab=expression(italic(a)~"-value"))`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround playing with unicode characters.

*p* is \U1D631 and *P* is \U1D617

```
plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab="p-value")
plot(1:10,cex.lab=1.25,ylab="\U1D631-value")
```

This solved my problem.